# Prove that that {$f_n$} does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\left\{f_n\right\}$ is given as $\frac{\sqrt{n}x}{2+\sqrt{n}x^4}$, prove that this function does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$. I tried to approach this question using the smallest upper bound:

$$\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|$$
$$=\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\left|\frac{\sqrt{n}x}{2+\sqrt{n}x^4}-\frac{1}{x^3}\right|$$
$$\geq f_n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}^3}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2} $$ as $n \to \infty$
which is $\neq \frac{1}{x^3}$ ?

But it is possible that $\frac{1}{x^3} = \frac{1}{2}$ by letting $x=2^{1/3}$. Which part did i get wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your claim. Shouldn't line 3 be $f_n(1/\sqrt n) - 1/(\sqrt n)^3$? Why should your answer to this be $=1/x^3$? You're taking a sup over all $x$. This is just very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n$ converges point-wise to $1/x^3$, but   $$\left|f_n\left(n^{-1/4}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{n^{-1/4}}\right)^3\right|=\left|\frac{n^{3/4}}{2n^{1/2}+1}-n^{3/4}\right|\to \infty .$$
So $f_n$ doesn't converge uniformally on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: You've got the pointwise limit wrong

Comment: @Wojowu oh yes!

Comment: I have now retracted the stupid downvote! :)

Comment: @pigeon does {$f_n$} not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ because {$f_n$} and {$f$} do not converge to the same limit? or is it because {$f_n$} not converge to 0?

Answer (score 0):

You showed that the maximum distance between $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ is at least $1/2$. The fact that the minimum distance between $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ is zero (achieved at the point $x = 2^{1/3}$) does not affect the maximum distance.

Another approach is to show that every $f_n(x)$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$, but $f(x)$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

For $x=0$, $f_n(0) = 0$ for all $n$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(0)=0$. For $x>0$,  $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = x^{-3}$.

Since $f_n$ is a rational function, we can differentiate:
$$
f_n'(x) = \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dx}\left[\frac{\sqrt n x}{2+\sqrt n x^4}\right]=\frac{2 \sqrt{n}-3 n x^4}{\left(\sqrt{n} x^4+2\right)^2}. 
$$
Since $2 \sqrt{n}-3 n x^4$ is a polynomial of degree $4$, it has $4$ roots, but only one of them is in $(0,\infty)$: $x_n = \left(\frac 23\right)^{\frac14}n^{-\frac18}.$ Since $x\mapsto x^{\frac13}$ is an increasing function, it follows that
\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)}|f_n(x)-f(x)| &\leqslant |f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|\\ &= \left|\frac{\sqrt n \left(\frac 23\right)^{\frac14}n^{-\frac18}}{2+\sqrt n\left(\left(\frac 23\right)^{\frac14}n^{-\frac18}\right)^4} - \left(\left(\frac 23\right)^{\frac14}n^{-\frac18}\right)^{-3}\right| \\ &= \left|\frac{ 2^{1/4} 3^{7/4} n^{3/4}-2^{15/4} \cdot 3^{1/4}}{24 n^{3/8}}\right|\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow \infty.
\end{align}
Hence $f_n$ does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: $f_n$ converges pointwise to $1/x^3$ for $x\ne 0$.

Comment: @bjorn93 Thanks for pointing out my error; I have corrected it.

Comment: Well, I meant $\frac{1}{x^3}$

Comment: @Math1000 Hi, I am wondering why $\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leqslant |f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)| \to \infty$ means {$f_n$} does not converge uniformly. Since $0 \leq \sup_{x\in(0,\infty)}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq |f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)| \leq \infty$, it is possible to have some function between $\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq |f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|$ that approach $0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: A sequence of functions $f_n$ on a set $A$ converges uniformly to $f$ if and only if $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{x\in A} |f_n(x)-f(x)| = 0. $$ Since I found an upper bound for the sequence $\sup_{x\in A} |f_n(x)-f(x)|$ which tends to infinity, it follows that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly.

Comment: @Math1000 kk, but the sup is the smallest upper bound, so even you found another upper bound that tends to infinity, the smallest upper bound can still be 0? For example, 0 <= sup < another upper bound -> infinity, sup here can also be 0,1,2...etc ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the supremum of
$$\left|\frac{\sqrt nx}{2+\sqrt nx^4}-\frac{1}{x^3}\right|$$
on the interval $(0,\infty)$. And I can't follow your work after that. It's not clear to me where that inequality came from. Note that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{\sqrt nx}{2+\sqrt nx^4}-\frac{1}{x^3}\right)=-\infty$$
Thus
$$\sup_{x\in (0,\infty)}\left|\frac{\sqrt nx}{2+\sqrt nx^4}-\frac{1}{x^3}\right|=+\infty $$
Since this is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it follows that we don't have uniform convergence on $(0,\infty)$. You can also say $d_n\to\infty$, where for each $n$, $d_n$ is defined as the supremum above.